# Trigger click on appended elements by $.each

Tags: jquery, html

I trying to append options to an existing select in HTML with this code

HTML:

```
<div class="booking-select-calender">
    <select id="booking-year-month">
    </select>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".booking-calendar-wrapper-in .month-title").each(function() {
    var month = $(this).text();
    $("#booking-year-month").append("<option>" + month + "</option>");
});
```

I want also do something when a user click on the option. I tried to add click function with **.on** or **.trigger** outside od each but it won't work.

Any tips what can be a good solution for this?

Comment: can you add html to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use on change handler but on your select element that i assume has id= #booking-year-month

```
$('body').on("change" , "#booking-year-month" , function() {
    console.log("selected option: " + this.value);
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I used like 1 hour on this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can simpley put onchange method on you select htmly tag

```
<select id="booking-year-month" onchange="YourNewMethod()"></select>
```

---

and rather than appending option in select element also add value attribute in options like this

```
$(".booking-calendar-wrapper-in .month-title").each(function() {
  var month = $(this).text();
  $("#booking-year-month").append("<option value='" + month + "'>" + month + "</option>");
});
```